# Reverse DNS nslookup fail

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

I'm having the following problem with my DNS configurations. I need to set up my reverse DNS and I don't know how.

1 -

```
# nslookup mx.websolutions.com.ar
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mx.websolutions.COM.AR
Address: 198.50.148.166
```

2 -

```
# nslookup 198.50.148.166
Server:127.0.0.1
Address:127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
166.148.50.198.in-addr.arpa   name = 166.ip-198-50-148.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
148.50.198.in-addr.arpanameserver = ns104.ovh.net.
148.50.198.in-addr.arpanameserver = dns104.ovh.net.
```

(EDIT 3rd RECORD - wrong ip)

My questions is how to correctly set up the PTR record.

Im using OVH VPS so i have an option to change Reverse DNS.
This is my reverse DNS : 166.ip-198-50-148.net

How do i point it to my mailserver? mx.websolutions.com.ar

Problem source:

```
Your IP address 198.50.148.166 is associated with the domain 166.ip-198-50-148.net.
Nevertheless your message appears to be sent from mx.websolutions.com.ar.

You may want to change your pointer (PTR type) DNS record and the host name of your server to the same value.

Here are the tested values for this check:

    IP: 198.50.148.166
    HELO: mx.websolutions.com.ar
    rDNS: 166.ip-198-50-148.net
```

Comment: The entity that manages the rDNS zone for that netblock has to set up the PTR records. This isn't something you can do unless you are that entity.

Comment: To add to joeqwerty's comment, you need to contact your ISP and ask them to create any reverse DNS records you need for the IP address(es) that the ISP has issued you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. You already have A record that says "mx.websolutions.com.ar" is "198.50.148.166", this is required for OVH VPS. So nothing to do here. This needs to be propagated well, so that OVH servers can see it that way (but you already have this, so just saying ...).
2. Log in to your [OVH manager](https://www.ovh.com/manager/web/login/)
3. Navigate to Web -> Platforms (left sidebar, in the middle of the screen) and select your VPS (something like vps123456.ovh.net)
4. At the bottom you have IP Addresses - click IP tab (the second one)
5. In the right bottom corner, click on Manage IP
6. You should see the table of IP addresses with third column being called "Reverse" or "PTR" or something like that. Click the "-" in this column on the row with your IP address. Then enter your host name "mx.websolutions.com.ar" and click OK sign.
7. Wait until propagated well (e.g. use [dns propagation checker](http://dns-propagation-checker.online-domain-tools.com/) to check that or just wait long enough).
8. You are done :)

Comment: I did what you said, ill wait for DNS to propagete. Hope this works for me :)

Comment: You did well: nslookup -q=ptr 198.50.148.166 gives me 166.148.50.198.in-addr.arpa     name = mx.websolutions.com.ar